# How can we Call method=post in the wcf service url?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{year}/{issue}/{article}")]
Article GetArticle(string year, string issue, string article);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/{year}/{issue}",Method="POST")]
Article AddArticle(string year, string issue, Article article);
```

My URL is http://localhost:1355/Issues.svc/

if I give this I am fetching all data from the database

http://localhost:1355/Issues.svc/2010/June/A

GetArticle method fires for the filtered data to bring from db.

Similarly I have to call the Add Article(WebInvoke) method to insert data in to the database.
How should I call this method in the browser how my url should be

Answer (score 1):

- Write a web page that uses **jquery** to [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to the page the JSON of your article.
- Use **Fiddler** to build a request. See [here](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/ui.asp) and [here](http://nayyeri.net/use-fiddler-to-test-restful-wcf-services).

Answer (score 0):

You can't post just by visiting a URL. That's what WebGet means, you visit it with a browser. To post you'd need to write a small dummy html-form page.